# iOS - How can I preload views to the memory in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

In XIB it works fine For me.

```
ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];

// preload views to the memory
[thirdVC view];

// setup fromviews array and toviews array
NSArray *fromViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.imageView1, self.imageView2, self.label1, nil];
NSArray *toViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:thirdVC.imageView1, thirdVC.imageView2, thirdVC.label1, nil];

[self pushViewController:thirdVC fromViews:fromViews toViews:toViews duration:1.0];
```

But when I preload views to the memory in storyboard, I don't know how I can use that.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"FourthVC" bundle:nil];
FourthVC *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FourthVC"];

NSArray *fromViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.imageView1, self.imageView2, self.label1, nil];

NSArray *toViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc.imageView1, vc.imageView2, vc.label1, nil];

[self pushViewController:vc fromViews:fromViews toViews:toViews duration:1.0];
```

Anyone can suggest how I can preload the views in storyboard?

Comment: What's the problem? Your code look correct? force call `viewDidLoad` by `[vc  view]` but not sure why would you need that

Comment: in Storyboard m not access object in array m moving xib to storyboard.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What problem exactly are you having with the 2nd block of code you posted in your question?

Comment: @rmaddy In second block I am access the three object "toViews" in the array but its getting  0 objects.

Comment: That means either `vc` is `nil` or `vc.imageView1` is `nil`. Use your debugger and determine which one it is.

Comment: Im am navigate the Thirdviewcontroller to ForthView and my 3rd view is XIB and FourthView is Storyboard.?

Comment: @rmaddy You are Riight `VC` and  `vc.imageView1` both is `nil`. I don't know why ?

Comment: If `vc` is `nil` then either `sb` is `nil` or you don't actually have a view controller named `FourthVC` in your storyboard. Again, check which one.

Comment: In 1st Block m navigate `XIB` to `XIB` am getting three objects Properly in `*toViews` the Problem is `Xib` to `Storyboard` .!

Comment: Your `FourthVC ` probably dont have the identifier, go to storyboard and add it, its below the class name declaration

Comment: @Tj3n m already add the  identifier.

Comment: @Tj3n Thanks M add `[vc view]` its my Mistake .

Comment: Also Thanks.! @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer Thanks to @Tj3n

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"FourthVC" bundle:nil];
 FourthVC *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FourthVC"];   

// preload views to the memory
 [vc view];

 NSArray *fromViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.imageView1, self.imageView2, self.label1, nil];

 NSArray *toViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc.imageView1, vc.imageView2, vc.label1, nil];

 [self pushViewController:vc fromViews:fromViews toViews:toViews duration:1.0];
```